# Whats the best way to populate an Array List and make it stick when page reloads

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, arraylist, thymeleaf

I have been trying to teach myself Java and I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for in regards to Array Lists.

My project has a form that when the page loads, it loads the few lists I've created, for example, business agency types in check boxes or business class that uses a list to show dropdown choices.

I have been writing the following code to populate the different field sections.

```html
    @GetMapping("/directBind")
    public String getDirectBind(Model model){
        DirectBind directBind = new DirectBind();
        List<String> businessAgencies = new ArrayList<String>();
        businessAgencies.add("Personal");
        businessAgencies.add("Commercial");
        businessAgencies.add("Life");
        businessAgencies.add("Benefits");
        businessAgencies.add("Health");
        businessAgencies.add("Non P and C");
        model.addAttribute("businessAgencies", businessAgencies);
        List<String> businessAgencyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        directBind.setBusinessAgencyList(businessAgencyList);

        List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies = new ArrayList();
        Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
        ams360Policies.add(ams360Policy);
        model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policies);

        List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
        billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
        model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
        ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);

        directBind.setDirectBox(true);
        directBind.setServiceLevel(true);

        List<String> businessClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        businessClasses.add("Animal Services");
        businessClasses.add("Bonds");
        businessClasses.add("Contractor");
        model.addAttribute("businessClasses", businessClasses);
        directBind.setBusinessClasses(businessClasses);

        model.addAttribute("directBind", directBind);

        return "directBind";
    }
```

My question is, is this truly the best way to create an array list, or should this be going somewhere else? Because it is only living in the "function that retrieves/loads the form" so any changes to the form, like letting the user add a new row/input field, will cause this chunk of code to have to then be rewritten in the addRow function. It just seems really redundant and I was wondering if there is a better place to add this. Like a separate controller function or a constructor function in the java class file?

I have also noticed that some input fields that the user types an answer into, will stay on the page when a new row is added, and some user inputs do not stay. Would also love help with that. Not sure if it's a connected issue because I am generating fields in different ways or if it's its own question.

Here is some of the Form's HTML:

```html
<form  class="ui form" th:object="${directBind}" th:action="directBind" method="post"  style="padding:0 10px;">
  <h4>Customer Setup</h4>
  <div class="row">
      <label >Contact Name (First/Last):</label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{contactName}" required="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <label for="formAddress">Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="formAddress" th:field="*{formAddress}" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <label for="website" style="margin-top: 1em;"> Website:</label>
      <input type="text" id="website" th:field="*{website}" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <label for="nameInsured">Name Insured:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nameInsured" th:field="*{insuredName}" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <label>Business with Agency:</label>
      <div th:each="businessAgency : ${businessAgencies}">
          <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{businessAgencyList}" th:value="${businessAgency}"/>
          <label th:text="${businessAgency}">Business with Agency</label>
      </div>

  </div>
<!-- Business Class Drop Down Field Below: -->
      <div class="row">
          <label>Business Class: </label>
          <div >
              <select class="form-control" th:field="*{businessClasses}" required="true">
                  <option th:each="businessClass : ${businessClasses}" th:value="${businessClass}" th:text="${businessClass}"></option>
              </select>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <label for="descriptionOfOps">Description of Operations:</label>
      <input type="text" id="descriptionOfOps" th:field="*{descriptionOfOps}" required="true" />
  </div>



  <div class="formFooter">
      <input id="send"  type="submit" value="send" name="send" class="btn btn-success finish" data-loading-text="Sent!" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are generating your static content every time that the REST endpoint is called. 
The first principle in connection with this that you might want to research is the[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). A good pattern for your case is [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) that is widely used and stands for the separation of these 3 layers: Model-View-Controller. There are frameworks that have built in support for this approach.

The Model should be a separate database or in memory storage where you keep your data - in your case the ArrayLists. You would save all changes here and serve the same data to every requester.

Right now you are keeping the Model data in the View part of your code, that is unfortunate for many reasons.

The Controller should be a middle-layer that retrieves data from the Model and serves it to the View.

[Here is a random simple example](https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp) on implementing this design principle that will help you get started. One class per layer should do for this case and you can build complexity as your service grows.

Comment: So put it in a method in the Model, and then call that method in each controller endpoint?

Comment: Yes, if you only want an in-memory storage then you can create an object for each type of data that you have. And when there is a request from the View side (your form), then the controller class can call the model class which can serve the requested object back to the controller and the controller will send it to the view.